# how to redirect the old subdomain to new subdomain with existing redirecting code for oldmaindomain to newmaindomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

it's a bit long title but what I mean is How to redirect old-subdomain to a new -subdomain with this existing code for my old-main-domain to new-main-domain in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tagon.app$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tagon.app$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://tagon.link/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

where to add the code for redirecting the subdomain to another subdomain here?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not 100% clear on what you are asking. Your code sample at the minute appears to work. Can you provide a clear "previous link" => "new link" example.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. what I mean is I want to redirect the "my.tag.com" to "my.tag.net "., because I already redirected the "tag.com" to "tag.net" with the .htaccess code above I mention.

but for the subdomains, I don't know how to redirect them to a new subdomain.